# GNU make - how to determine name + path of makefile from --print-data-base output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When you do `make all --print-data-base`, you get this kind of output after a given makefile is done being executed:

```
...
# default
LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
# default
OUTPUT_OPTION = -o $@
# environment
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS = C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/qt5binaries/plugins
# default
COMPILE.cpp = $(COMPILE.cc)
# environment
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
# makefile (from 'Makefile', line 1)
MAKEFILE_LIST :=  C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/ImpTarget.mk Makefile
# environment
TMP = C:/Temp
...
```

The current directory is simply equal to `CURDIR` - not shown - but the name of makefile is not so straightforward.

Looking at [6.14 Other Special Variables: MAKEFILE_LIST](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables), it seems the answer is: look at the first entry of `MAKEFILE_LIST` and that's the name of the makefile. However, if you pass in a makefile to `make` via `make all --print-data-base MAKEFILES=MyMake.mk`, then the first entry will be `MyMake.mk`.

Therefore, the rule appears to be: look at the variable `-*-command-variables-*-` and determine if a makefile has been passed in. If yes, discount it from the variable `MAKEFILE_LIST` and the first string from the remaining entries is the name of the makefile.

**QUESTION**

Are there any other 'gotchas' that would insert something in var `MAKEFILE_LIST` in front of the real makefile?

Comment: The short answer is that `MAKEFILE_LIST` contains a space-separated list of filenames which are the makefiles make parsed, in the order in which make parsed them.  So any capability which causes make to parse makefiles, will modify this list.  That includes the `MAKEFILES` variable, the names provided to the `-f` option on the command line, the names provided to any `-f` options that appear in the `MAKEFLAGS` or `GNUMAKEFLAGS` variables, and any `include` directives.  That's all I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @MadScientist from the output of `make` is it possible to infer whether any makefile was passed in using `MAKEFILES=`? That's all I really need.

Comment: You mean, from the output of `make -p`?  Why not just examine the contents of the `MAKEFILES` variable that's printed out?

Comment: @MadScientist The problem is the `MAKEFILE=` since if it's used to pass in a makefile, the makefile passed in gets placed at beginning of `MAKEFILE_LIST` so I need a way to detect that. Is the commandline used to invoke a given makefile stored in its `-p` section?

Comment: @MadScientist check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `-*-command-variables-*-` in the `--print-data-base` output and if it exists and sets the var `MAKEFILES` - as in `make all MAKEFILES=thing.mk` - then you know that whatever it is set to will appear in every `MAKEFILE_LIST` first i.e. before the name of the actual makefile.

When you cross-reference with

```
MAKEFILE_LIST :=  thing.mk Makefile cfg.mk
```

You'll know that the name of the current makefile is `Makefile` and everything appearing after are makefiles read in because they were `include`d at the top.